# MediaPlayer и конфликт звука

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Использую в программе вывод коротких звуковых файлов через след код:

```
public static void _play_music(Context ctx, String _file) {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            if (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ctx.getString(R.string.net1) + "/Sound/" + _file).exists()) {
                is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ctx.getString(R.string.net1) + "/Sound/" + _file);
            } else {
                if (new File(_path_apk_api30 + "/Sound/" + _file).exists()) {
                    is = new FileInputStream(_path_apk_api30 + "/Sound/" + _file);
                }
            }
            mp.setDataSource(is.getFD());
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer::start);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(mp2 -> {
                mp2.stop();
                mp2.reset();
                mp2.release();
                mp = null;
            });
        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
        }
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Но есть проблема, на некоторых устройствах звук выводится одновременно со звучанием радио например, а на других устройствах звук радио выключается радио при появлении любого звука из программы.

Речь идёт об автомобильных устройствах ММС.

В чём может быть проблема?

UPD. Прочитал об аудиофокусе, возможно проблема в радио у пользователя, программа не получает разрешения на одновременное воспроизведение?

Comment: Зависит от реализации потери фокуса в приложении. Кто-то делает уменьшение громкости, кто-то ставит на паузу.

Comment: Да, скорее всего так, вы правы